# Battery 9V for control remote car

Tags: power, batteries, motor

I'm taking part in a car remote control and line following contest.

Contest organizers require the battery to be <= 9 V, and don't allow using low-voltage circuit.

I'm using a 18650 battery (3.7 V/cell; if fully charged, up to 4.2 V). When using two cells, we only have 8.2V. It is not enough for the car to go uphill (slope is 20 degrees).

I want to find some kind of battery to create 9 V (can merge some cells) and supply a big enough discharge current.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the extra 0.8V will solve the problem? My suspicion is that the motors may not be geared right.

Comment: Yes, i tried that.

Comment: Actually, the error can be 0.5V. That mean, I can use 9.5 battery.

Comment: I tried with 9.2V battery and it passed

Comment: Have you considered using a boost-converter to step-up the 7.4v nominal of 2x 18650 to some higher voltage? Also, the 18450 cells found in many discarded e-cig units will supply more current than cheap 18650 cells will. Yesterday I found one containing a 19500 cell with 1.7Ah capacity. It was in an IGET GOAT aloe grape unit, whose web-page falsely claims 1.8Ah (https://igetvapesaustralia.com/products/aloe-grape-iget-goat)

Comment: No,I am not allowed to use boost-converter too

Comment: @MrCR - then I'd also consider using 6 Alkaline cells, since that will give you 9v. New-cell voltages will range from 1.50 to 1.65v, depending on the purity of the chems inside. But most of all, it sounds like either the challenge is designed to make you really think about how to drive these particular motors, or that they're simply a poor choice for the project. The motors in the RC cars I had growing-up would climb a 20 deg incline when they were 95% discharged and do about 30kmh when fully charged (about 5x NiCd AA)